# Combining two or more MySQL procedures in one SQL file

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I am creating a c# program which reads a `.sql` file and automatically execute it. The problem is that, inside the `.sql` file should be a procedure. I have 20+ procedures created. I can successfully execute it when there is only one procedure inside my `.sql` file. How will I combine all procedures inside one `.sql` file? I tried the following:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UpdateSettledMemo`(res_id varchar(45))
BEGIN
UPDATE memo_reservation SET reservation_memostat = 'SETTLED' WHERE
reservation_id = res_id;
END$$

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UpdateUnsettledMemo`(res_id varchar(45))
BEGIN
UPDATE memo_reservation SET reservation_memostat = 'UNSETTLED' WHERE
reservation_id = res_id;
END$$
```

but nothing is created. The only error it returned is *An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll. Fatal error encountered during command execution*

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: *"Doesn't work"* is not very descriptive of the actual behavior you observe. Does it return an error? Does the first procedure get created, but not the others? There's very little information given about *how* the contents of the file are being executed by the c# program. Is this invoking the mysql command line client, as an external executable? "Doesn't work" is the antipathy of a description of a problem.

Comment: A question you might want to ask yourself is, "do I really need to read from a .sql file?" The reason I say this is because it would be much better to do this programmatically using SqlCommands with SqlParameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `.sql` file, remove the `DELIMITER $$` at the beginning of every procedure. Also, replace `$$` with a semicolon (`;`) after `END` at the end of every procedure. Your query inside the `.sql` file should be:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UpdateSettledMemo`(res_id varchar(45))
BEGIN
UPDATE memo_reservation SET reservation_memostat = 'SETTLED' WHERE
reservation_id = res_id;
END;

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `UpdateUnsettledMemo`(res_id varchar(45))
BEGIN
UPDATE memo_reservation SET reservation_memostat = 'UNSETTLED' WHERE
reservation_id = res_id;
END;
```

Fatal error is displayed when you use variables without allowing it inside your connection. MySQL sees @data and expects to find a parameter named @data.  When it doesn't find one it throws an exception.

To fix this add `allow user variables=true` to your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this would be to use a delimiter in the `.sql` file itself, but have it after `--`, so that mysql will ignore it as a comment.
For instance, if your delimiter is `<NewQuery>`, just write in the `.sql` file `-- <NewQuery>`.
In your c# program you can split the `.sql` file by the `-- <NewQuery>` delimiter and run each segment alone.